# Not able to change chart.js x and y font colors

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I tried changing the xticks color of chart js but somehow this is not working. This is the cdn I am using.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.4.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>   


    function plot(x, y, chartTitle, labelText) {
    $("#canvasCard").html(
      '<canvas id="myChart" width="600px" height="600px"></canvas>'
    );
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: x,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: labelText,
            data: y,
            backgroundColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
            ],
            borderColor: [
              "rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)",
              "rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)",
              "rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)",
              "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
              "rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)",
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        plugins:{
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: chartTitle
      }},
        scales: {
                        
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
          xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontColor: 'green'
            }
        }]
     
        },
      },
    });

  }
```

[Doesn't have any effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARs0l.png)

I googled the problem and many of them have listed the same thing as it is in the scales object. Still it isn't working. Any help appreciated
Thank you in advance.

Comment: regarding to css, have you tried color: instead of fontColor?

Comment: yeah...I found that ultimately it is decided by Javascript/Chart.js. I have to change it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! In v3.4.1 or v3 and above chart js has different description.

**Trying this worked. So this works**

```
scales: {
                    
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks:{
          color: "white"
        }
      },
      x:{
        ticks:{
          color: "white"
        }
      }
 
    }
```

**Instead of the following code. The following works in previous versions.**

```
scales: {
                    
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            fontColor: 'green'
        }
    }]
 
    }
```

Thank You.